# Controller constructor function executing multiple times in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So my problem is that `Controller` constructor executes multiple times. If I have 2 `Directives` associated with particular `Controller` then it runs `2 + 1`, if 3 `Directives`, then `3 + 1`... and so on. If I have an ajax request in that controller to get data, then it runs that much times which isn't really necesarry...

Why is it so? I'm very concerned that it makes all those extra unnecessary ajax requests...

**HTML:**

```
 <span ng-controller="MenuController as MenuCtrl">
    <main-menu></main-menu>
 </span>
```

**Controller:**

```
  var howManyTimes = 0;
  angular.module("shredkit", ["myDirectives"])

  .controller("MenuController", function(){
    ++howManyTimes;
    console.log("HOW MANY TIMES? THAT MANY: " + howManyTimes )
  })
```

**Directive:**

```
angular.module("myDirectives", [])

  .directive("mainMenu", function(){
    return{
      restrict:"E", // type of directive - 'E' - element
      templateUrl:'templates/main-menu.html',
      controller:"MenuController",
      controllerAs: "MenuCtrl"
    };
  })
```

Comment: You dont need to have the `ng-controller` on your span tag if you're going to using the directive that calls that controller too.  (See Bens answer below)

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You controller run once for the ng-controller tag:

```
 <span ng-controller="MenuController as MenuCtrl">
```

And every time you initiate a new DOM element in which this scope is in controll on:

```
 controller:"MenuController"
```

This happens because controllers in angular are not singletones, they are being constructed and initated on every use.

If your intend to use multiple controller because you want to share pieces of data please do it in the following 2 ways:

1. have a parent controller wrapping all childrens
2. use a shared service to hold state

Comment: Is it correct to assume - one controller per one directive?

Comment: @fjckls more likely to say one controller per one dom element who define this controller, can be a directive can be not

Answer (score 1):

You use MenuController in your div and also in your directive (same one). Obviously, controllers are executed for each element they are assgined to including assignment in directive